# React / TypeScript - Type '{ index:number}' is missing the following properties from type 'IList': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Using React, and I have defined two interfaces, ICard, IList:

**ICard**

```
interface ICard {
    id: any;
    text: string;
    index?: number;
    list?: number;
}
```

**IList**

```
interface IList extends Array<ICard> {
    index?: number;
}
```

I want to create a type which is a list of IList, which I will use in a separate component that sites above IList and holds this list of lists. I have tried to define my list of lists in a setState as:

```
const [lists, setLists] = useState<IList[]>([{index: 0}]);
```

however the error that I am getting is in the title and is as follows:
`Type '{ index:number}' is missing the following properties from type 'IList': length, pop, push, concat`
I am unsure what the solution is as I am new to TypeScript / JS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure, it should be `listIndex:0` in `useState` and not `index:0`?

Comment: Your type says you are extending Array and adding a new property `index`, yet when you initialize your 'state', you are not passing an array, and just an object with an unrelated property name `listIndex`

Comment: Editted to correct errors

Comment: your `IList` is an `Array of ICard ` and `state` is an array of `IList`. So default Value should be something like:  `const [lists, setLists] = useState<IList[]>([[{index: 0}]]);` isn't it?   As `IList[]` is Array of `IList`, which is in turn Array of `ICard`

Comment: @Rohit I want to make an IList[] and initialise single IList in the setState call, not a card in one of my list in my IList[], which is what [[{index: x}]] would do.

Answer (score 1):

You are extending the basic `Array` type, so typescript expects an `IList` to have all the properties of an array, when you're expecting it to simply have the properties of a single `IList` object, plus the `index`.  You probably want to create an array of extended `ICard` types:

```js
interface CardWithIndex extends ICard {
    index?: number;
}

type IList = Array<CardWithIndex>
```

Or you can just declare what type you expect the state variable to be, as @RohitKhanna said:

```
const [lists, setLists] = useState<CardWithIndex[]>([{index: 0}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I want to have a separate component IList which when hovered over by an object of type ICard, assigns to the card's list property, it's index. So the IList does need to be a separate component with the property, not just an array. Do you know of a way I can do this?

Comment: Just as a side note, what is the difference between your state variable setting and what I wrote in my answer:const [lists, setLists] = useState<IList[]>([{index: 0}]);?

Comment: Oops good catch, I meant `useState<CardWithIndex[]>([{index: 0}])`, I edited my answer

Comment: In regards to what you're trying to do, I'm struggling to understand.  Perhaps you could explain it better?  "when hovered over by an object of type ICard" doesn't make sense...`ICard` is just an object with a few properties.  Are you talking about a component with `(props: ICard)`?  This sounds like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  Perhaps you could go back to your question, describe the entire scenario as clearly as you can, explain what you're trying to accomplish, and then we'll be able to see why your typings are giving you trouble.